# SpringBoot oracle Stored procedure call raise "exception [null]: java.lang.NullPointerException" where I did attach parameter values to the call

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

I'm trying to call a stored procedure on an oracle DB , I did create entity and repo for the procedure , however , when i initiate the call I get "java.lang.NullPointerException" ...
please note that I do have another procedure within the same project which is working fine ..

Entity:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "MsgEntity.submitMsg", procedureName = "PROC_SUBMITMSG", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "PARAM1", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "PARAM2", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "PARAM3", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "PARAM4", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "PARAM5", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "RESULT1", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "RESULT2", type = String.class),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "RESULT3", type = String.class)}
```

Repo:

```
    Map<String, String> submitMsg(@Param("PARAM1") String PARAM1,
                                  @Param("PARAM2") String PARAM2,
                                  @Param("PARAM3") String PARAM3,
                                  @Param("PARAM4") String PARAM4,
                                  @Param("PARAM5") String PARAM5,);
```

Call:

```
Map<String, String> smsBillResponse = smsRepository.submitMsg("value1","value2","value3","value4","value5");
```

Log:
`ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-1) Forwarding to error page from request [/foo/fooo/foooo] due to exception [null]: java.lang.NullPointerException`

I did try to call the procedure directly on the DB using DBeaver and it's working fine ..

Comment: Seems like your Entity requires Param3, but you submit param2 twice instead of Param3. Is that on purpose?

Comment: well , i mistyped here but in the code it's param3 , thx anyway